# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

When I added Image to my classifier for training then it throws some exceptions. We are using the Mobilenet model of ml5.js in which when we call train() method.

```
    let features =  ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet');
    const classifier = features.classification();
    console.log("setup classifier DONE", classifier);

    var img2;
    console.log("adding images");
    const gorra = new Image();
    gorra.src = "https://ml5js.org/docs/assets/img/bird.jpg";
    gorra.width = 224;
    gorra.height = 224;
    console.log("adding images DONE", gorra);

    img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = "{!$Resource.cat}"
    img2.width = 224;
    img2.height = 224;
    console.log(img2);

    var img3;
    img3 = new Image();
    img3.src = "{!$Resource.car}"
    img3.width = 224;
    img3.height = 224;
    console.log(img3);
    console.log("setup classifier");

    var img4;
    img4 = new Image();
    img4.src = "{!$Resource.car1}"
    img4.width = 224;
    img4.height = 224;
    console.log(img4);

    console.log("setup classifier");
    console.log("adding example image...");
    const ex =  classifier.addImage(document.getElementById('imgshow'), "Gorra");
    console.log("adding ex image DONE!...", ex);
    const ex1 =  classifier.addImage(img2, "Gorra");
    console.log("adding ex1 image DONE!...", ex1);
    const ex2 =  classifier.addImage(img3, "car");
    console.log("adding ex1 image DONE!...", ex2);
    const ex3 =  classifier.addImage(img4, "car");
    console.log("adding ex1 image DONE!...", ex3);
    console.log('claasifier'+classifier);
    console.log("Training");
    // const trainer ;
    setTimeout(function(){ const trainer = classifier.train(); console.log("Training DONE", trainer);}, 30000);
```

after adding image whenever train() run it throws this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYh7Q.png)
which is taking reference of Mobilnet.js library, I have highlighted the line where it causes that error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wqbc.png)

please let me know, how can we resolve this.

Comment: Hi. Can you please edit your post in order to add the errors that is been throw to the console when you run your code?

Comment: ```img2.src = "{!$Resource.cat}"``` What does this line of code suppose to do? Are you trying to add a URL to ```img2.src```?

Comment: @Vivek img2.src taking src or path of that image which I'm taking from the static resource.

Comment: this type of problem is mostly happening when you not put your jquery file path in a proper order.

Comment: @ANKITSHARMA``` taking from the static resource``` -> Can you post that part of the code?

Comment: @Vivek by using "{!$Resource.cat}" we can add that. I'm doing this salesforce just by adding image in static resource and getting that image in code by using tag '$Resource'

Comment: Salesforce.. That wasn't mentioned in your question.

Comment: Can you post the result of ```console.log(img2);``` ?

Comment: Here you go - <img src="/resource/1546509863000/car" width="224" height="224"> @Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a callback for the `.train()` function.

From the documentation for [ml5js](https://ml5js.org/docs/FeatureExtractor), the callback for `.train()` function is **not** optional.

You can replace your train statement

```
const trainer = classifier.train();
```

with the below code.

```
const trainer = classifier.train(function(lossValue) {
  console.log('Loss is', lossValue)
});
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.
As of now its worked for a local data set, is it possible to store those data set into their server(i.e: In their Model or in Database)?